# Best practice for 404 page for API

Tags: json, api, rest, http-status-code-404, httpresponse

I am writting REST API now. I faced with one problem - how 404 page in api should look like.
Of course it will be better to show user link to the API documentation.
But what about page in general.
Should it be beautiful page or just simple text also in JSON or XML format.
If page has a lot of images/scripts, we have to use network connection inefficiently.
Surely, we can get only headers of http response but it seems to be bad solution.

I have looked on several well-known APIs and the way how do they implement 404 pages.

Both Flickr and Twitter has 404 pages with some images, css.

But Github has pretty simple response, just JSON with following content.

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

I think this is good example of response (without images and css) if not please correct me.

So my question is what is the best practice for the 404 API response, should it be pretty simple (like on GitHub) or it is better to add some other useful information about API.

Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone request an API  they will most likely catch the 404 exception and look for the HttpStatusCode. If it's 404 they don't need more information and just report that the User (?) is not found.
So it doesn't really matter what you do as 99% of the request won't even download the response site

Comment: But why do they use different pages for main site (https://github.com/asdasdasdsadsa) and for API pages (https://api.github.com/sadsa) ?

Comment: @CROSP There's no real reason for this. A simple json error message simply better fit to an API.

Comment: What about content of this response only url ,like above, to the API documentation ?

Answer (score 1):

A `404 Not Found` response in an *API* is not required to have any content at all. The client code will probably look at the status code before it looks at the content of the request.

Every REST client code I've written so far does not concern itself with the body of a `404 Not Found` response. I can not imagine anything in the body that has any use above the fact that the resource was not found.

Comment: What is the purpose of github response message than.

Comment: Ask GitHub. I didn't write their API.